# invoke angular service call inside "then(function(){})"

Tags: angular, angular-promise

I have a requirement when the user clicks on the button I need to take a screenshot of that view and send back to the backend save it as pdf in DB and download the same. I am using DOM to Image angular package, Its able to take a screenshot and convert it to image and can be saved as to client system.

```
public takeScreenShot(){

   domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('my-node'))
      .then(function (blob) {
         window.saveAs(blob, 'my-node.png');
        //I need to make a call to my service to send this blob object to backend.
   });
}
```

I did try to call my service after saveAs but my service instance doesn't exist inside then

```
public takeScreenShot(){
    let serviceObj= this.service;    
    domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('my-node'))
        .then(function (blob) {
        window.saveAs(blob, 'my-node.png');
        this.service.sendImage(blob).subscribe(res=>{//save as pdf to client system but this.service doesn't exist inside then.
        //I did try to return blob and assign it, it doesn't work.
       });  
  });
```

I need to call my service inside then not sure how can you please help me in this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must use arrow function syntax to be able to access `this`

```
public takeScreenShot(){
    let serviceObj= this.service;    
    domtoimage.toBlob(document.getElementById('my-node'))
        .then((blob) => {
            window.saveAs(blob, 'my-node.png');
            this.service.sendImage(blob).subscribe(res=>{//save as pdf to client system but this.service doesn't exist inside then.
            //I did try to return blob and assign it, it doesn't work.
       });  
  });
```